# Get path to file that is included into a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following situation: I want several independent Makefiles to include a single file with all the rules (via `include ...` directive). So far, so good. However, that central rules file does need to use some other files next to it (shell-scripts and such). To name these other files, it needs to know its own path relative to the `make` invocation.

What would work is this:

```
# in the Makefiles
toolsPath := ../../generalStuff
include $(toolsPath)/generalRules.mk

# in the generalRules.mk
foo: ./$(toolsPath)/script
    ./$(toolsPath)/script foo
```

Yet, while this would work, it relies on the including Makefiles to honestly tell the general file its own path. And I'm wondering whether there is a way to avoid setting a `toolsPath` variable.

**Is it possible to replace the `$(toolsPath)` in the included file with something that relies on `make` itself, rather than the including Makefiles?**

I would like to be able to simply write this into the Makefiles:

```
include ../../generalStuff/generalRules.mk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MAKEFILE_LIST`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-including-_0028MAKEFILE_005fLIST-variable_0029) variable (see the example in the link) can be used to find this information.  Just be sure you obtain it before another `include` hides it.

Comment: Thank you. It's a bit bulky to have to use `$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))`, but it definitely delivers what I need. However, I think it would be good to expand this answer with a short description of what `MAKEFILE_LIST` does, and how to extract the current path. That would make it more helpful for future readers.